# GDALWarp returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, gdal

GDALWarpDestName returned NULL without setting an error

i am trying to resample several raster (in tif) to coarse resolution, while the gdalwarp running result null

```
def resam(inDs):
 gdal.Open(inDs)
 (shotname,extension) = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(inDs)) # get the filename and extension
 outDs = shotname+'_232_ave'+extension      #result tif of resample
 gdal.Warp(outDs, inDs,
              format = 'GTiff',
              xRes = 232.03572204, yRes = 232.03572204,
              resampleAlg = gdal.GRA_Average)
if __name__ == '__main__':
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
        inDs = file # input tif
        resam(inDs)
```

the expected result should be resample all the files in current path directory to the xRes*yRes resolution, that is 232.03572204.

Answer (score 1):

"GDALWarpDestName returned NULL without setting an error" can be caused by bad or invalid input, so check your inDs.

[An example with bad URL input.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238680/error-in-downloading-subarea-using-gdal-warp-systemerror-error-return-without)

[An example with invalid filename input](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2016-June/044652.html) (Click prev thread for more details).

Comment: Solved! Thanks, it is the files problem. I should add an if to select only files with .tif